# how do i divide list into smallers list

Tags: python

My list is formatted like:

```
gymnastics_school,participant_name,all-around_points_earned
```

I need to divide it up by schools but keep the scores.

```
import collections

def main():
    names = ["gymnastics_school", "participant_name", "all_around_points_earned"]
    Data = collections.namedtuple("Data", names)    
    data = []

    with open('state_meet.txt','r') as f:   
        for line in f:
            line = line.strip()
            items = line.split(',')
            items[2] = float(items[2])
            data.append(Data(*items))
```

These are examples of how they're set up:

```
Lanier City Gymnastics,Ben W.,55.301
Lanier City Gymnastics,Alex W.,54.801
Lanier City Gymnastics,Sky T.,51.2
Lanier City Gymnastics,William G.,47.3
Carrollton Boys,Cameron M.,61.6
Carrollton Boys,Zachary W.,58.7
Carrollton Boys,Samuel B.,58.6
La Fayette Boys,Nate S.,63
La Fayette Boys,Kaden C.,62
La Fayette Boys,Cohan S.,59.1
La Fayette Boys,Cooper J.,56.101
La Fayette Boys,Avi F.,53.401
La Fayette Boys,Frederic T.,53.201
Columbus,Noah B.,50.3
Savannah Metro,Levi B.,52.801
Savannah Metro,Taylan T.,52
Savannah Metro,Jacob S.,51.5
SAAB Gymnastics,Dawson B.,58.1
SAAB Gymnastics,Dean S.,57.901
SAAB Gymnastics,William L.,57.101
SAAB Gymnastics,Lex L.,52.501
Suwanee Gymnastics,Colin K.,57.3
Suwanee Gymnastics,Matthew B.,53.201
```

After processing it should look like:

```
Lanier City Gymnastics:participants(4)
```

as it own list

```
Carrollton Boys(3)
```

as it own list

```
La Fayette Boys(6)
```

etc.

Comment: If you compress the list to just contaion the participant count, how are you going to keep the scores individually ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend putting them in [dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries):

```
data = {}

with open('state_meet.txt','r') as f:   
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        items = line.split(',')
        items[2] = float(items[2])
        if items[0] in data:
            data[items[0]].append(items[1:])
        else:
            data[items[0]] = [items[1:]]
```

Then access schools could be done in the following way:

```
>>> data['Lanier City Gymnastics']
[['Ben W.',55.301],['Alex W.',54.801],['Sky T'.,51.2],['William G.',47.3]
```

**EDIT**: 
Assuming you need the whole dataset as a list first, then you want to divide it into smaller lists you can generate the dictionary from the list:

```
data = []

with open('state_meet.txt','r') as f:   
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        items = line.split(',')
        items[2] = float(items[2])
        data.append(items)

#perform median or other operation on your data

nested_data = {}        
for items in data:
    if items[0] in data:
        data[items[0]].append(items[1:])
    else:
        data[items[0]] = [items[1:]]

    nested_data[item[0]]
```

When you need to get a subset of a list you can use slicing:

```
mylist[start:stop:step]
```

where `start`, `stop` and `step` are optional (see [link](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/introduction.html#lists) for more comprehensive introduction)

Comment: but i have to use the list as a whole first to find the mean median first and last score then dived them back school and find the mean median first and last for each school